# Constructor over-injection due to presentation layer 'dashboard'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, domain-driven-design

I'm currently having some design problems with a controller on my presentation layer (web application). The website should offer some kind of dashboard, which shows all kind of information that will be gathered from several repositories. I'd like to show the newest.. *alerts*, *messages*, *timeline events*, *report statistics*...

```
public class HomeController : Controller {

    public HomeController(
        IAlertRepository alertRepository, 
        IAccountRepository accountRepository, 
        ITimelineRepository timelineRepository,
        IReportingRepository reportRepository) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

This completely leads to a constructor over-injection which is awkward for many reasons. How can I get over this problem? Displaying all of the information is a requirement of our customer.

Comment: If the constructor parameter list is too long then perhaps instead of using constructor injection you can use something like a service locator and lazy-load the repository objects through that?

Comment: How much work is `HomeController` doing? Maybe it should just be provided a collection of generic `IRepository` objects? That said, how many of these do you have? If this is a top-level dashboard, having only 4 isn't that bad and quite manageable.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is a viable option for you, but you could consider creating totally separate controllers for each of those dashboard objects

e.g.

```
AlertsController
AccountsController
TimelineController
ReportsController
```

And then you only haveto inject a single repository into each. Each controller would render a `Partial View`, and you would invoke them each from the client-side via Ajax with content-type of `text/html`, and then insert the returned markup into your main document into the relevant container element (e.g a `<div>`)

In that respect, `HomeController` would be relegated to more of a "bootstrapper" role, serving only to load up the initial page framework and client-side script.

Advantages of this approach would be that your dashboard widgets can be loaded asynchronously, refreshed independently, reused individually, plus it's very easy to allow the user to choose different combinations or indeed just open the different widgets up separately in a new window, etc, with no extra code.

Of course that might not suit the context of your app :)

Comment: This is a great idea I've already came up with by myself because as I experienced, it's a very common 'practice' to have many individual widgets on a dashboard. However, there's another requirement to that project to reduce and bundle requests as much as possible. If the dashboard needs to show 10 different things, then I need to make 10 partials which invoke 10 requests to 10 controllers. I don't think our domain expert will be happy about that.

Comment: That's a fair point; perhaps you could use a single request from client side, indicating what widgets you want, parameters for them, etc, and use HttpClient on the HomeController to make the 10 individual requests (which being local will have very low overhead), assemble the resulting HTML in your Index view and return from HomeController in a single roundtrip.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor over-injection informs yo that `HomeController` is doing too much. Controllers are responsible for sending model/data to the view and grabbing user input to pass it on in an appropriate service.

That service is what you miss here. Create a service that talks to repositories to find the relevant data and has all the business logic of manipulating them (which now you probably have in you controller, breaking the [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)). Still, if your service class talks with too many repositories, break it to more service classes, one role for each.

You might end up with 2-3 more classes, but these can be reused from other controllers or services, and your design will become more modular.